# Calc Content-MD5 in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, md5, afnetworking

I'm attempting to calculate the content-md5 header for the payload of a multipart-form upload:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload"   
parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
  [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.png"  
mimeType:@"image/png"];
}];
```

I tried to read the `HTTPBodyStream` :

```
if ([request HTTPBodyStream]) {
    NSInteger result;
    uint8_t buffer[1024]; 
    while((result = [[request HTTPBodyStream] read:buffer maxLength:1024]) != 0) 
    {
        if(result > 0) {         
            [data appendString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)buffer]];

        } else {...}
    }
```

But I end up in an infinite loop. Is there a way to do this?

***UPDATE***

`[[request HTTPBodyStream] streamError]` returns `null` at the end of the `while` loop if I break the while loop if `result < 0`, however the stream will be incomplete.

Comment: I'm assuming your `else {...}` breaks from the loop?

Comment: Yes, possibly. But from the docs, it states `A negative number means that the operation failed`. Should it fail since I'm not reading off the network?

Comment: I'm not sure if `NSURLConnection` allows reading from `file://` urls (which I assume is what you mean). If you get 0 or <0, you need to break from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about using hasBytesAvailable && in case of reading less than max buffer size (1024).It means that EOF was reached.

`while([[request HTTPBodyStream] hasBytesAvailable] && [[request HTTPBodyStream] read:buffer maxLength:1024]) == 1024)'

Comment: Unless I'm understanding wrongly, the buffer is temporarily only during the `read:buffer` method and does not contain the entire thing?

Comment: Also, the result was < 0 which was a `A negative number means that the operation failed.`

Comment: `0` indicates that the end of the buffer was reached;
`A` negative number means that the operation failed.

Comment: But anyway in case of reading less than maximum number of bytes. it's a sign of failure or a data chunk should be last